# Dialog is unintended vertically flipped

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

I'm using WebGL and Chrome.

The application I created consist of several webpages.
Upon switching to a next page a dialog is popping up to indicate that a new page is being loaded.
Sometimes this dialog is vertically flipped (due to race condition?)
This (and other) dialog stay vertically flipped) when I move back and forward through the webpages.

I can solve it by zooming in the browser.

Is anyone familiar with this problem

Comment: Could you provide a link to your code so we can see the error in action?